# $X$ is covering space of $Y$ and $Y$ is covering space of $X$. Is it necessarily $X \approx Y$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

This problem just came to my mind. It looks easy, but i can't do it. Is there any counterexample of the problem given in the title?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are the two spaces path connected?

Comment: Hint:  There is a counterexample with $X$ a wedge of two circles.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman You can assume that they are path connected

Comment: @JasonDeVito can you say a bit more? The question, whether the covering maps are mutually inverse, obviously has to be answered to the negative, any two nontrivial endo-coverings $\Bbb S^1 \rightarrow \Bbb S^1$ will do. But any space is homeomorphic to itself. I read the question as "can covering maps detect isomorphism classes?". So we need *two* non-homeomorphic mutually covering spaces. If you allow non-connected spaces the disjoint union of a space with itself should provide a counterexample. But I am not so sure about the connected case.

Comment: @JonasLinssen:  I was originally thinking of $X = S^1\vee S^1$ and $Y = S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$.  Because $\pi_1(X)$ (which is isomorphic to the free group on two generators) contains a copy of $\pi_1(Y)$, $X$ has a covering with the homotopy type of $Y$.  I originally was thinking that this covering was actually homeomorphic to $Y$, but now I'm not so sure.